# BufferAggregate

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In the ongoing saga of me rewriting functions that can be easily composed from existing Rx functions, I present my latest progeny: a bastard combination of Scan and Aggregate. The aim is to aggregate *n* items from a source, and emit the result every *n*. Then start again.

```
public static IObservable<T> BufferAggregate<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
                                                Func<T, T, T> aggregator, int size)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var count = 0;
        var current = default(T); 
        return source.Subscribe(t =>
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
                current = t;
            else if (count < size)
                current = aggregator(current, t);
            else // (count == size)
            {
                observer.OnNext(aggregator(current, t));
                count = 0;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note that there is a good reason for not using pure Buffer, which is that the data items are rather large, so it is preferable to calculate the aggregate as we go along, rather than doing it all at the end.

Am I complicating things too much?

Comment: Since there is no accepted answer, do you need more reviews on your current solution? I could point out a few more problems and things to consider if you want. For example, you are ignoring `onCompleted` and `onError` so your new sequence can never complete.

Answer (score 4):

- Because the objects which are represented by `T` are the providers of notifications I would like to suggest to rename `current` -> `currentProvider` and `t` -> `provider` which makes it more clear what they are about, neither `current` nor `t` are good names.
- the method argument `size` should be renamed as well. Because you said in the question `The aim is to aggregate n items from a source, and emit the result every n.` the argument should be name `blockSize`.
- you should use `braces` although they might be optional because  braceophilia can lead to serious hard to track bugs.
- the else part `else // (count == size)` looks like you had an `else if` but decided to skip it in favour of the `else`. Although you save one comparision in the way you have it now, I would like to suggest to revert this to an `else if` wich makes the intent more clear.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
public static IObservable<T> BufferAggregate<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
                                        Func<T, T, T> aggregator, int blockSize)
{

    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var count = 0;
        var currentProvider = default(T);

        return source.Subscribe(provider =>
        {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
            {
                currentProvider = provider;
            }
            else if (count < blockSize)
            {
                currentProvider = aggregator(currentProvider, provider);
            }
            else if (count == blockSize)
            {
                observer.OnNext(aggregator(currentProvider, provider));
                count = 0;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't use pure `Buffer`, as you need to calculate and aggregate as we go. The good news is, Rx has a build in function that can do this for you. Very similar to `Buffer` is it's cousin [`Window`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html).

Now, given this tip, the implementation is pretty straight forwards:

```
source.Window(size).SelectMany(chunk => chunk.Aggregate(aggregator))
```

I am not even sure if this warrant an extension method.